# Cannot embed non-ASCII in string

Tags: c++, c

When I try to add a non-ASCII character in a string, g++ (v 4.7.3) gave warning. The output is totally unexpected. '23 00 25 30`;

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *p = "\x03123";
    printf("%02x %02x %02x %02x\n", p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

I got error

```
g++ -std=c++11 te2a.cc
te2a.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
te2a.cc:5:12: warning: hex escape sequence out of range [enabled by default]
te2a.cc:5:12: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
```

Comment: Octal escapes are limited to 1-3 digits; hexadecimal escapes have no upper bound on the number of digits, so you have to ensure that there is a non-hex character at the end.  Note that the 25 and 30 in your output are completely unspecified because you're accessing beyond the end of the (2-character) string pointed at by `p`.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out I have to use either

```
"\x03\x30\x31\x32\x33"
```

or

```
"\0x03""123"
```

Guess I was spoiled by scripting language (such as perl) where it's ok to have `"\x03123"`.

Comment: The rationale for this surprising convention is that C supports platforms where the `char` type may have more than 8 bits. If `char` has say 12 bits, one needs 3 hex digits to represent all values.  In the early days of C, octal was more commonly used and computers had bytes with anywhere from 6 to 9 bits, hence the limit to 3 octal digits, hex escape sequences were introduced later.